# How do you solve $\frac{|x^2+5x+6|}{|x|-3} = 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

How do you solve

$ \frac{|x^2+5x+6|}{|x|-3} = 1 $   ?

I have tried rearranging, polynomial division, multiplying both sides by a a fraction to simplify to no avail for the last hour.

Comment: Distinguish cases for $x>0$, $x<0$, $x^2+5x+6>0$ and $x^2+5x+6<0$.

Comment: Looking at a graph and concluding the answer is not the same as solving. Therefore, I find the answer of Rajada the only correct one.

Comment: It is a visual hint and a good way to see why/how to chop up the domain into the various cases when finishing the proof, which I alluded to at the end of my solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want $\frac{|x^2+5x+6|}{|x|-3}=1$, that implies $|x^2+5x+6|=|x|-3$ as long as $|x|-3\ne 0$. Graph both equations simultaneously, and you will see they intersect at exactly $1$ spot: $(-3,0)$. Unfortunately we must reject the solution since it makes $|x|-3=0$. Thus there is no solution.

By graphing them, you will also be able to see how to chop up the domain in order to evaluate all the possibilities alluded to in the hints and other solutions provided.

Comment: Why the down vote? My assumption is that this is a precalculus question and described a solution that is commensurate with the assumed skill of the student.

Comment: I downvoted, because if this is indeed commensurate with his skill, then your answer will not improve his skills, while Rajada's answer provides insight into the mathematics behind the question (and yours does not).

Answer (score 5):

$$ \frac{|x^2+5x+6|}{|x|-3} = 1 \implies |x^2+5x+6|=|x|-3$$

**Solving Algebraically:**

**Case$1$:** When, $x <-3$,

$$ x^2+5x+6=-x-3 \implies x^2+6x+9=0 \implies x=-3 \text{ [No solution]. }$$

**Case$2$:** When, $-3 < x \leq -2$,

$$ -x^2-5x-6=-x-3 \implies x^2+4x+3=0 \implies (x+3)(x+1)=0 \implies x=-3,-1 \text{ [No solution from this case]. }$$

**Case$3$:** When, $-2 < x \leq 0$,

$$ x^2+5x+6=-x-3 \implies x^2+6x+9=0 \implies x=-3 \text{ [No solution from this case]. }$$

**Case$4$:** When, $x > 0$ but $x \neq 3$,

$$ x^2+5x+6=x+3 \implies x^2+4x+3=0 \implies \implies (x+3)(x+1)=0 \implies x=-3,-1 \text{ [No solution from this case]. }$$

So, the answer is no solution.

**Solving Geometrically:**

As mentioned by  Laars Helenius.

You can plot both $|x^2+5x+6|$ and $(|x|-3)$ on the same plot and check for the intersecting point, and that will be your answer. But you have to check whether those solution points in your domain. In this case, you will get one point $-3$, but your function domain is $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{-3,3\}$. So, no solution.

[image]

Comment: x=-3 is not in the domain of the original equation!

Comment: Good fix. Looks good now.

Comment: Yes, later I noticed and changed accordingly. Please check the edited version. Please, let me know if you find anymore slips in the calculation. Thanks, @LaarsHelenius.

Comment: I like the edit. Graphing is not proof, per se, but it gives a lot of visual hints on what to do.

Comment: Thanks. Tried to tag you, but not able to do so.

Comment: Certainly just a typo, but the domain is actually $\mathbb{R} \backslash \{\pm3\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You can rewrite the numerator as $|(x+2)(x+3)|$.  From there you can figure out the cases for which the expression inside the absolute value is negative and for which it is positive (and rewrite the numerator appropriately, i.e. as either $x^2 +5x+6$ or $-(x^2 +5x+6)$), which will also help you decide whether to rewrite $|x|$ as either $x$ or $-x$.